# Termination issue with sed

Tags: shell, sed, quoting

In a sed script, I have the following line, which needs to be updated by `sed`:

```
opennic="nameserver 95.85.9.86\nnameserver 185.83.217.248\nnameserver 193.183.98.154\nnameserver 5.9.49.12"
```

The `sed` command looks like this:

```
sed -i.bak s/^opennic=\".*\"/opennic=\"${u}\"/g /absolute/path/to/script.sh
```

and `$u` is:

```
nameserver 104.238.153.178\\nnameserver 141.138.157.53\\nnameserver 45.63.91.109\\n
```

The error message I get is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command
```

I assume there is something wrong with the escape characters in `$u`, but I just can't put my finger on it.

How do I get my `sed` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for the `sed` command:

```
$ sed -i.bak "s/^opennic=\".*\"/opennic=\"${u}\"/g" /absolute/path/to/script.sh
```

Without quotes, sed will be executed with multiple arguments. Splitting the `$u` variable in multiple arguments by its spaces.

Something like the following (each line is one different argument):

```
$ sed \
  's/^opennic=".*"/opennic="nameserver' \
  '104.238.153.178\\nnameserver' \
  [...]`
```

And there, the first `s/^[...]` command will be uncompleted.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you very much!